# template string of es6 in attribute of react component

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I can use a double and single quote to concatenate my dynamic variable but template string is cleaner. I got an unexpected token, any clue why?

```
...
return (<UserList id={subactions} key=`applications${query.status}` />)
...
```

Comment: Please add a tag for your environment/framework.

Comment: would `key={'applications'+query.status}` work?

Comment: would `key={\`applications${query.status}\`}` work?

Answer (score 19):

You need to change it to the code below.

```
return (<UserList id={subactions} key={ `applications${query.status}` } />)
```